# How to assign keys to an object converted from array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure and I would like to change keys name from this

```
let FIELDS = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
let {...obj} = ['123','John','Doe', null]
console.log(obj) //  {0: '123', 1: 'John', 2: 'Doe', 3: null}
```

to something like this

```
console.log(obj) //  {id: '123', first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
const values = ['123', 'John', 'Doe', null]

const object = Object.fromEntries(fields.map((f, i) => [f, values[i]]))

console.log(object)
```